# Equivalence test with random effects

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, nested-data, equivalence

I am designing an experiment where I will test different subjects’ multiple times under two different conditions (lab and real life)

My hypothesis Is that that the subject will perform equivalent in the different conditions.

It will make sense to test the subject multiple times since performance can vary. I will also need to test them in groups.

Therefore it will make sense to me to use a linear mixed model during the analysis

```r
lmer(seconds  ~  condition + (1 + condition | subject / testgroup ), data = .)
```

Pretty new to the equivalence test and is unsure of how to move forward.

How would this model be used in equivalence testing?

Comment: This blog post looks like exactly what you want https://pedermisager.org/blog/mixed_model_equivalence/ The parameters package has the `equivalence_test` function as well. https://easystats.github.io/parameters/reference/equivalence_test.lm.html

Comment: Thank you! @ErikRuzek!